# How to Extract the li tag content present inside the Div tag using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get the data which is present inside the div class **"credit-list linelist"**

From the site

https://www.usgbc.org/rpc/LEED%20V4%20BD+C:%20HOMR/v4/1593?location=Littlefield,%20Arizona&lat=36.9161976&lng=-113.95254890000001

**Updated Code,**

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import csv
import re
import json
import sys
import psycopg2
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


def resultSetGetter(databasename, ip, username, pw):
    States = ['Nevada']
    StateList = ','.join('?' for i in range(len(States)))  # '?,?'
    try:
        con = psycopg2.connect(database=databasename, user=username, password=pw, host=ip, port=5432)
        cur = con.cursor()
        # newPrimaryCity = '\'' + primary_city + '\''
        # queryString = "select DISTINCT primary_city from loc_zip_code_details where primary_city = " + newPrimaryCity + ";"
        # print queryString
        queryString = "select distinct(loc_zip_code_details.primary_city),state_name from loc_zip_code_details,loc_state where loc_zip_code_details.state_code = loc_state.state_code and loc_state.state_name IN (%s) ORDER BY state_name,loc_zip_code_details.primary_city limit 1"
        in_p = ', '.join(list(map(lambda x: '%s', States)))
        sql = queryString % in_p
        cur.execute(sql, States)
        # print cur.execute(queryString)
        # print queryString
        zipCodes = cur.fetchall()
        print zipCodes
        return zipCodes
        # zipCodes= [x for x in foo if x!= ("Alba", "Texas")]
        con.close()

        # print zipCodes
    except psycopg2.Error as leed_Error:
        print leed_Error


def flatten(x):
    result = []
    for el in x:
        if hasattr(el, "__iter__") and not isinstance(el, basestring):
            result.extend(flatten(el))
        else:
            result.append(el)
    return result


def leed_data(zipCodes):
    for i in zipCodes:

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.get("http://www.usgbc.org/rpc")

        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainCol"]/div[1]/div[1]').click()
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainCol"]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[10]').click()
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainCol"]/div[1]/div[2]').click()
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainCol"]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[2]').click()
        time.sleep(1)

        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="edit-address"]').clear()
        # print i
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="edit-address"]').send_keys(i)
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="geocode"]/div/div[1]/div[2]').click()
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search-text"]').click()
        time.sleep(3)

        # alpha = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('views-field-field-category-logo-fid')
        # temp = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="credit-list linelist"]').extract()
        # print alpha.text()

        html_list = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainCol"]/div[5]/ul')

        items = html_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")

        a, b, c, d, e, a1, b1, c1, d1, newList, e1 = [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

        for item in items:
            txt = item.text.split('\n')
            txt.append(i)
            # print txt
            txt[3] = txt[3].split(',')
            newList = flatten(txt)
            print newList
            # txt = flatten(txt)
            # print txt
            # a1=re.search(pattern, txt[2]).group(0)
            # b1=re.search(pattern, txt[1]).group(0)
            newList[2] = int(''.join(w for w in txt[2] if w.isdigit()))
            newList[1] = int(''.join(w for w in txt[1] if w.isdigit()))
            a1  = newList[2]
            b1 =  newList[1]
            c1=newList[0]
            d1=newList[3]
            e1=newList[4]
            #d1=d1.split(',')
            #print d1
            #txt.append(d1)

            # newList = newList.append(txt)
            print newList
            a.append(a1)
            b.append(b1)
            c.append(c1)
            d.append(d1)
            e.append(e1)

        # print i
        df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': a, 'col2': e, 'col5': d, 'col3':b, 'col4': c})
        print df
        driver.close()
        #appendCsv = pd.DataFrame()
        #appendCsv.append(df,ignore_index=True)

    #new_df = pd.concat(appendCsv,ignore_index=True)
    df.to_csv('LEED_NEVADA1.csv', index=False, header=False)
    #return df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    databasename = ""
    ip = ""
    username = ""
    pw = ""
    # print databasename,ip,username,pw
    zipCodes = resultSetGetter(databasename, ip, username, pw)
    zipCodes = [','.join(map(lambda x: x.replace(' ', ''), y)) for y in zipCodes]
    # display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
    # display.start()
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
        'credentials_enable_service': False,
        'profile': {
            'password_manager_enabled': False
        }
    })
    chrome_path = r"/usr/bin/chromedriver"
    finalList = leed_data(zipCodes)
    #print finalList
    #df = pd.DataFrame(finalList)
    #finalList.to_csv('Leed1.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

My input File Will be as a CSV from the database,

"LittleField,Arizona"
"Gilbert,Ariznona"

I got the output like,

```
0    20  Nevada    30                        Annual energy use  Alamo
1     3  Nevada     5  Efficient hot water distribution system  Alamo
2     1  Nevada     1           No environmental tobacco smoke  Alamo
3     2  Nevada     3                      Compact development  Alamo
4     2  Nevada     3            Construction waste management  Alamo
5     7  Nevada    12                          Total water use  Alamo
6     4  Nevada     6                         Indoor water use  Alamo

0    20  Nevada    30               Annual energy use  AmargosaValley
1     1  Nevada     1  No environmental tobacco smoke  AmargosaValley
2     2  Nevada     3             Compact development  AmargosaValley
3     1  Nevada     2             Community resources  AmargosaValley
4     2  Nevada     3   Construction waste management  AmargosaValley
5     7  Nevada    12                 Total water use  AmargosaValley
6     4  Nevada     6                Indoor water use  AmargosaValley
```

I want to append that output into a csv.

Comment: Are you looking for an optimized solution or a different output?

Comment: @Mokshyam, Optimised Solution.

Comment: Also Virtual Display is not working in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `regex` + `pandas dataframe` or `string-digit-check` + `pandas dataframe`:

```
%%timeit
html_list = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainCol"]/div[5]/ul')

items = html_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
a,b,c,a1,b1,c1 = [],[],[],[],[],[]

#pattern = re.compile(r'\d+')

for item in items:
    txt = item.text.split('\n')    
    #a1=re.search(pattern, txt[2]).group(0) 
    #b1=re.search(pattern, txt[1]).group(0)
    a1=int(''.join(w for w in txt[2] if w.isdigit()))
    b1=int(''.join(w for w in txt[1] if w.isdigit()))
    c1=txt[0]    
    a.append(a1)
    b.append(b1)
    c.append(c1)

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': a, 'col2': 'Littlefield Arizona', 'col3':b, 'col4': c})  

    col1     col2           col3    col4
0   10  Littlefield Arizona 30  Annual energy use
1   2   Littlefield Arizona 3   Compact development
2   1   Littlefield Arizona 2   Access to transit
3   1   Littlefield Arizona 2   Heat island reduction
4   2   Littlefield Arizona 3   Rainwater management
5   6   Littlefield Arizona 12  Total water use
6   4   Littlefield Arizona 6   Indoor water use
```

`114 ms ± 3.31 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

I've commented an alternative: using regex to precompile and search for the regex.

Comment: i want the states to take from the input, Please do refer the above updated code. @Mokshyam